# SCOM: recalculatemonitoringstate() issues

Tags: windows, powershell, scom

have an issues with a script, trying to recalculate the info in the SCOM via powershell script. Got an issues with a recalculation.

```
#imput parameters
Param(
[Parameter(Mandatory=$False)]
[string[]]$computerName
)
Import-Module OperationsManager
#Main SCOM server var
$computerName = "SCOMserver"
#Connect to the SCOM-Mgmt Server
New-SCOMManagementGroupConnection -ComputerName $computerName

#Get all the SCOMalert filtered queue warning state 
$alerts = Get-SCOMalert -ComputerName $computerName | Where-Object {$_.Owner -eq “user01” -and $_.ResolutionState -eq “0” -and $_.IsMonitorAlert -eq $true} 
Foreach ($ActiveMonitor in $alerts)
{
    $ActiveMonitor.recalculatemonitoringstate() | Test-SCOMMonitoringTaskResultForError
}
```

Error which i get:
Method invocation failed because [Microsoft.EnterpriseManagement.Monitoring.MonitoringAlert] does not contain a method named 'recalculatemonitoringstate'.

Answer (score 1):

When you get an error like that, it's worth googling.

In this instance, it's correctly informing you that you're trying to call a method (`RecalculateMonitoringState()`) which this object does not have. Check out  [the `MonitortingAlert` class documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.enterprisemanagement.monitoring.monitoringalert.aspx).

This class is relevant because you are using [**`Get-SCOMAlert`**](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh918457(v=sc.20).aspx) which is returning an object of this type (in the variable `$alerts`)

The `RecalculateMonitoringState()` method is  part of [the `MonitoringObject` class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.enterprisemanagement.monitoring.monitoringobject.aspx), so it's likely you're after [**`Get-SCOMMonitor`**](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh918469(v=sc.20).aspx).

Comment: Hello, thank you for responding. (i am little bit slow in powershell) from your answer i understood that if i find something what is bounding these two Get-SCOMMonitor and Get-SCOMalert like example ID and can grep data from Get-SCOMalert ID in to the variable and loop it with recalculation in the Get-SCOMMonitor. (besides i am googling but it is hard then you are not sure what you are trying to find)